# How can I make ADW_EX wallpaper stick?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, amazon-kindle-fire, adw-launcher-ex

When I set new wallpaper, it lasts only until the next sleep. On waking, the default ADW sequence of wallpapers resumes.  I can re-select the wallpaper and it will again persist again until the device sleeps.

I've tried:

- Locking the desktop - doesn't lock the wallpaper.
- Upgrading to v 1.3.3.56 - same behavior
- Restarting ADW after setting the wallpaper - the wallpaper persists, but still only until a sleep.

How can I make it stick?

ADW.launcher EX 1.3.3.1 
Kindle Fire 6.3.1, not rooted
Android 2.3

Comment: Are you using ADW presets?

Comment: No, at least I haven't intentionally invoked any.  Are you suggesting them as the possible cause or a possible solution (and how)?

Comment: I guessed it as possible cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this free app, [My Kindle Wallpaper](https://kindlecooltricks.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/change-kindle-fire-wallpaper-without-rooting/) which does this simply and easily, no root required. D/l & install it, and point it at a photo or a folder full (on the KF, not on the net), and get your favorite background photo or cycle through several (one per wake-up, the way the stock software does). Works perfectly on my original KF with KF v6.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Kindle Fire is designed to restore its wallpaper on every wake, and that to prevent it, you have to have rooted the KF, and use a file manager to remove the system's write permission from the new wallpaper file.  See [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1362543) on xda-developers forum.